# Which scenarios we want to use constructor injection and spyon() injection? and which one is best?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

My Componenet `MaintainCOCComponent` constructor have an parameter for `MaintainCOCService` which is have  API call method service.

```
export class MaintainCOCComponent {

constructor(
   private maintaincocservice: MaintainCOCService) { }
}
```

### Constructor injection:

Here i have configured testBed and injected with a mock `MockMaintainCOCService` service via provider

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
  declarations: [MaintainCOCComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: MaintainCOCService, useClass: MockMaintainCOCService }]
});
```

### SpyOn Injection

Here I have mocked that real service by using SpyOn.

```
providers: [
            { provide: MaintainCOCService, useClass:MaintainCOCService }]

_maintainCOCService = fixture.componentRef.injector.get(MaintainCOCService);
spyOn(_maintainCOCService , 'Method1')
            .and.callFake(function (key, value) {
                return 1;
            });
 spyOn(_maintainCOCService , 'Method2')
            .and.callFake(function (key, value) {
                return 2;
            });
```

> we can directly pass the mock service in provider instead of mocking every method using spyon.So which scenario we want use Constructor injection  and which scenario we want to use Spyon Injection? and  and which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when ever you need to mock the entire service, you will use the `Constructor Injection` mock, for example, you have a service that uses FB SDK on its internals, you don't want that your tests will go "out" to FB, so usually the best practice it to build a mock Service that implements the same interface and mock it in the entire app.

The `spyOn` method usually is use-full when you need to check some service that got the correct params. what that service doe's after the function call is usually not so interesting.

Small Note, sometimes the usage of `spyOn` can indicate that you are testing the implementation rather then the specification.

Comment: Which one is best to use while the service having only two methods?

Comment: If you want to mock "all the methods" (in your case 2 method) i would used the constructor injector method.

Comment: Good! But is there any difference while using constructor injection and mocking two methods by using spyon? In my guess, length of code is difference?

Comment: No, the first is enabled only with the framework you are using (Angular) the second one is more generic & framework agnostic.