# getting `then is not a function` error while mocking http promise service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, observable

Original service

```
getVersionDataValuesforPopup(Docversion, versionname, Structureweek, docVersionFieldID, versionid, WLTP) {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'GetElementPopUpData?docVersion=' + Docversion + '&versionVariant=' + versionname
            + '&structureWeek=' + Structureweek + '&docVersionFieldID=' + docVersionFieldID
            + ' &VersionId=' + versionid + ' &isWLTP=' + WLTP, { withCredentials: true })
            .toPromise().then(responce => <CoCCreateVersionPopupPage[]>responce.json())
            .catch(error => {
                return error;
            });
    }
```

Calling original service in component

```
this.createversionservice.getVersionDataValuesforPopup(this.cocviewversiondatapage.docVersion,
            this.cocviewversiondatapage.VersionDescriptions,
            this.cocviewversiondatapage.structWeek, dataitems.DocumentVersionFieldId, this.cocviewversiondatapage.Id,
            this.cocviewversiondatapage.WLTP)
            .then(
            data=> { ...});
```

Mock service via [constructor injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636390/which-scenarios-we-want-to-use-constructor-injection-and-spyon-injection-and)

```
getVersionDataValuesforPopup(Docversion, versionname, Structureweek, docVersionFieldID, versionid, WLTP) {
        return Observable.of({ Result: {} });
    }
```

I got an error while test the method

> TypeError: this.createversionservice.getVersionDataValuesforPopup(...).then is not a function

I know the reason for the error, I am using `Observable` in my mock service but the real  service has `promise`, So then callback does not support.Kindly let me know  how can write a mock service for a `http` promise service call.

Comment: I will suggest some thing like this: `return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(null); });`

Comment: What I need to import for that??

Comment: You need to import nothing.

Comment: @Nour Yup. that is working for me. Could you please post this as an answer. i'll mark that a correct answer

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve({}); });
```

Answer (score 2):

What testing framework are you using?

I would create a spy, for example with Jasmine:

`spyOn(createversionservice, 'getVersionDataValuesforPopup')`

you can then check that your function was called.

If you want to return a promise you can use the .andReturnValue() method, for example:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve('result');
spyOn(createversionservice, 'getVersionDataValuesforPopup').andReturnValue(promise);
```

Similar spys will exist in other frameworks

You can then check the method was called (or whatever test you want, for example:

```
expect(createversionservice.getVersionDataValuesforPopup).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: I got this error because I didn't have that function name in my mock service

Comment: Solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved using below code:

`Promise.resolve({then: jest.fn()})`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. 
It also solves if you get the same error for .catch block. 

Promise.resolve({then: jest.fn(), catch: jest.fn()})